# jQuery UI - Cannot read property 'ui' of undefined

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I need to get a script working, which could be used on every possible Website in the world. First of all I need a current version of jQuery. If no jQuery or an old version is running the script will first add jQuery. The second step is to add jQuery UI.

The problem is: If a current version of jQuery is running, everything works fine. Otherwise I always get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ui' of undefined

Anyone can help me? My JS-Code:

```
var $tx;
    //Check if a current version of jQuery is runnig.
    if (window.jQuery) {
        $tx = jQuery;
        if( jQuery().jquery.replace(".", "") < 17.1 ) {
            addjQuery();
        } else {
            addNoConflict();
        }
    } else {
        addjQuery();
    }

    // Get jQuery Version

    function addjQuery() {
        loadScript("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js", function(){
            $tx = jQuery.noConflict(true);
            addNoConflict();
        });
    }

    // Add Script which requiers jQuery and jQuery UI

    function addNoConflict() {
        loadScript("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js", function(){
            var script = document.createElement("script")
                script.type = "text/javascript";
                script.src = "https://www.tariffuxx.de/services/js/txTarifrechnerScript.js";
                document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
        });
    }

    // Load required Scripts

    function loadScript(url, callback){
        var script = document.createElement("script")
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        if (script.readyState){  //IE
            script.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if (script.readyState == "loaded" ||
                        script.readyState == "complete"){
                    script.onreadystatechange = null;
                    callback();
                }
            };
        } else {  //Others
            script.onload = function(){
                callback();
            };
        }
        script.src = url;
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Where is the console pointing to with this variable `ui`?

Comment: you're not giving us all of your code.  There's no reference to a variable or property named `ui` anywhere.

Comment: I have some more information.the problem occours in line 11 `$.ui = $.ui || {};` of http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js

If I delete  `$tx = jQuery.noConflict(true);` in `addjQuery` function everything works fine even if an older jQuery Version is runnig on the website. Can anyone explain why `$tx = jQuery.noConflict(true);` comes to the error message?